# SQLite Listview Returning Empty Rows Of Data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a listview and created it with an arrayadpter but when i try to add data it shows empty rows for everytime ive tried to empty data, ive checked the database and the information is getting entered just never showing on the rows. Code Below:

```
public class Column_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Income>{


    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ArrayList<Income> incomes;
    public int viewResource;

    public Column_Adapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Income> incomes){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, incomes);
        this.incomes = incomes;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        viewResource = textViewResourceId;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(viewResource, null);

        Income income = incomes.get(position);



        if(income !=null) {
            TextView infoView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expense_type);
            TextView amountView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expense_amount);
            TextView budgetView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expense_budget);
            if (infoView != null) {
                infoView.setText(income.getiDate());
            }if(amountView != null){
                amountView.setText(income.getiAmount());
            }if(budgetView != null){
                budgetView.setText(income.getiMethod());
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Layout template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/expense_budget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/eExpInc"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/expense_amount"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/expense_amount"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/expense_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/eDefaultType"
        android:layout_marginRight="52dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/expense_amount"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/expense_amount"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/expense_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:text="@string/eDefaultAmount"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As seems you forget this

```
public int getCount() {
    if(incomes!=null)
    return incomes.size();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i cant seem to see the problem i checked the database and the data is being entered its just showing empty lines for each new record so its not the database

Answer (score 0):

the link below is having code that will help you

http://www.mediafire.com/file/wy6pv7664jp5m8m/CustomListviewAdapterExam.7z

this will be having setter and getter class,on listadapter class and one activity